# Simple JS MouseEvent and KeyboardEvent not working

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I would expect this simple js/html example below to click the input and write the letter Q.

What am I doing wrong here?

```js
var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true,
  view: window
});
document.getElementById('writeToMe').dispatchEvent(evt);

var e = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true,
  key: "Q",
  char: "Q"
});
document.getElementById('writeToMe').dispatchEvent(e);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="writeToMe">
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you try to accomplish your goal in such a complicated way?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="writeToMe">

window.onload = function(){
    var event;
    //click handler
    .addEventListener("click",function(){
        alert("clicked");
    },false);


    //This is true only for IE and firefox
    if(document.createEvent){
        // To create a mouse event , first we need to create an event and then initialize it.
        event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
        event.initMouseEvent("click",true,true,window,0,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0,null);
    }
    else{
        event = new MouseEvent('click', {
            'view': window,
            'bubbles': true,
            'cancelable': true,
          key: "Q",
          Char:"Q"
        });
    }

    writeToMe.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

Comment: [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent)  `initMouseEvent` is deprecated